# How to display PDF file and URL data from database as icon or image? Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdf, url

first, i am trying to display the uploaded pdf file but i don't know which type of data i should use, right now i'm using (Mysql) - varchar(191)

but it shows me this:

https://i.ibb.co/NY3LpnJ/1111.png

this is the code from the controller:

```
$req->validate([
        'file2' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:2048',
    ]);
    $fileName = time().'.'.$req->file2->extension();  
    $req->file2->move(public_path('uploads/form2'), $fileName);
    $table->file2=$req->file2;
```

so how to display it as a downloadable pdf file?

---

second,

i created a database and linked it to a form,

and i am displaying the data from database in admin panel page

but how can i display these two rows as icons?

https://i.ibb.co/V9C2r0q/22222.png

i want to be able to download the pdf file if i pressed the icon, and i want to be able to go to the link if i pressed the url icon

here is the code:

```
<tr class="text-right">
            <td>{{ $row->vid2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->file2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->how2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->wb2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->pb2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->why2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->projectname2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->icnumber2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: you need to upload the file then need to add full url of file `temp` location will not work

Comment: @KamleshPaul , may i know how to do this?

Comment: `Sorage::put()` use this